# Image swap in PHP

Tags: php, image, time

I am trying for Time Based Image Swaping by using this following PHP Script, but is not functioning properly as the image 'night.jpg' getting into effect by 17:00 hrs and the image 'morning.jpg' is not appearing, at all.  Please help me out to resolve this issue.  The code which I am using for the purpose is as follows:-

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
$hour= date('G');
if($hour > 5 && $hour < 7){
    echo '<img src="morning.jpg">';
}
else if($hour > 7 && $hour < 12){
    echo '<img src="day.jpg">';
}
else if($hour > 12 && $hour < 17){
    echo '<img src="noon.jpg">';
}
else if($hour > 17 && $hour < 19){
    echo '<img src="evening.jpg">';
}
else{
    echo '<img src="night.jpg">';    
}
?>
```

Comment: you only check for < and > but what happens if its for example exactly 17? then the else (thus night.jpg) gets displayed. Try it like this: else if($hour >= 17 && $hour < 19) ... etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for the great help.  It worked like a charm.  Shyam Ponkunnam

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comment by @xeraphim, your `if` conditions aren't correct, if we read your code it does the following:

- [6, 7] **morning**
- [8..11] **day**
- [13..17] **noon**
- [18, 19] **evening**
- [7, 12, 17, 19..5] **night**

If you want to get the right conditions, change your `>` symbols by `>=`